# Is the set closed, open, or neither?

Tags: general-topology, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Consider $C[0,1]$, the normed linear space of all real-valued continuous functions within the given interval. The norm endowed on this space is $\|f\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$.

Consider the subset $M := \{ f\in C[0,1] : (\exists c\in[-2,1])(\forall x\in [0,1])(f(x)=c)\}$ of $C[0,1]$.

We want to show whether this subset is open, closed or neither. Intuitively given $[0,1]$ and $[-2,1]$ are closed subsets then $[0,1] \times [-2,1]$ would also be closed.

By definition, $M$ would be closed if and only if for every sequence $(x_{n})_{n \in \mathbb  N} $ in $M$ that converges to a point $ x \in C[0,1]$, the limit is in $M$.

So assume we have a sequence $(x_{n})$ in $M$ such that $(x_{n}) \to {x}$ as ${n} \to \infty$

By the continuity of $C[0,1]$ this assumes that  $f(x_{n}) \to f({x})\in M \subset X$ as ${n} \to \infty $.

Using the norm, $0 \le \|f(x_n)-f(x)\|_{\infty} = \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x_n) - f(x)| \le \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x_n)| + \sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)|$

Am I going the right way with this? Or would I hit a contradiction?

Thanks :)

Comment: In your definition of closed, you need $x_n \in M$.

Answer (score 2):

The set $M$ consists of the constant functions whose constant value lies in $[-2,1]$.

The function $\phi:C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$, $\phi(f)(t) = f(t)-f(0)$ is linear, and $\ker f$ consists of functions that are constant.

The function $\eta:C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ , $\eta(f) = f(0)$ is linear.

Can you show that $\phi, \eta$ are continuous?

How can you express $M$ in terms of the intersection of the inverse images of closed sets under $\phi,\eta$?